# How can I create a proc_macro2 span programmatically?

Tags: rust, rust-proc-macros

I am working on a procedural macro which implements a small DSL.  Currently I am attempting to implement diagnostics-based error reporting, so that I can provide high quality feedback in the IDE setting.

My overall approach is to use the `Diagnostic` API of the [`proc-macro-error`](https://docs.rs/proc-macro-error/latest/proc_macro_error/) crate to create diagnostics.

This API should allow me to emit localized errors like so:

```
Diagnostic::spanned(span, Level::Error, text).emit();
```

The problem is, the [`spanned`](https://docs.rs/proc-macro-error/latest/proc_macro_error/struct.Diagnostic.html#method.spanned) method takes a [`proc_macro2::Span`](https://docs.rs/proc-macro2/1.0.19/proc_macro2/struct.Span.html) as an argument, a struct which has no constructor available.

Based on the nature of the DSL, it is not possible for me to use any `Span` from the input `TokenStream`.

How can I create a `Span` for use in this diagnostic?

Answer (score 0):

spanned method takes Span which is S: MultiSpan
you can use any of those functions to get the span

```
def_site()

call_site()

mixed_site()
```

You didn't mention your exact code for better elaboration, so hope the above help

You can also check this link

https://doc.rust-lang.org/proc_macro/struct.Span.html#method.call_site